# Merge two .csv files and add missing rows?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable

I have two files. `A.csv`:

```
date,colA
2016-01-01,1
2016-01-02,4
2016-01-03,2
```

And `B.csv`:

```
date,colB
2016-01-01,2
2016-01-03,4
```

I'd like to combine these to get equivalent of:

```
date,colA,colB
2016-01-01,1,2
2016-01-02,4,0
2016-01-03,2,4
```

So I want to append colB to original data and all missing dates from `B.csv` should have value 0 added. The resulting data will be plotted with pgfplots.

Is this possible with **LaTeX, pgfplots or pgfplotstable**? We can safely assuma that `A.csv` has all the needed dates.

Or is it possible to add the missing rows first to `B.csv` before merging?

My current solution is to add the missing rows manually and then use `\pgfplotstablecreatecol[copy column from table=...` macro.

EDIT: I'm using Overleaf so the solution should work there aswell.

Answer (score 2):

Well,if you have R and you admit `knitr` as LaTeX solution, then is easy:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim,xcolor}
\begin{filecontents*}{A.csv}
date,colA
2016-01-01,1
2016-01-02,4
2016-01-03,2
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{B.csv}
date,colB
2016-01-01,2
2016-01-03,4
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
<<echo=F,results='asis'>>=
A <- read.csv(file="A.csv")
B <- read.csv(file="B.csv")
C <- merge(A,B,by="date", all=T)
C[is.na(C)] <- 0
write.csv(C, file="C.csv",quote=F,row.names=F) 
@
Contents of \fcolorbox{gray}{gray!20}{\texttt{C.csv}}:~~~~~
\parbox{6cm}{\verbatiminput{C.csv}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I'm using Overleaf and I guess they don't have R/knitr support. I'd prefer pgfplots(table) solution.

Comment: @Paapaa In ShareLaTeX this code works out of the box but A.csv and B.csv should be made previously (i.e, without filecontents)

Comment: Ok, good to know! Will definitely try ShareLaTeX if there is no solution that works without R/knitr.

Answer (score 2):

How about this solution, not requiring R? Uses only LaTeX and the `datatool` package

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}{A.csv}
date,colA
2016-01-01,1
2016-01-02,4
2016-01-03,2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{B.csv}
date,colB
2016-01-01,2
2016-01-03,4
\end{filecontents*}

% \DTLloaddb{A}{A.csv}
\DTLloaddb{B}{B.csv}
\DTLloaddb{C}{A.csv}

\DTLforeach{C}{\Date=date}{
    \DTLgetvalueforkey{\tmp}{colB}{B}{date}{\Date}
    \DTLappendtorow{colB}{\DTLifnull{\tmp}{0}{\tmp}}
}

\begin{document}

\DTLsetseparator{,}
\DTLsetdelimiter{"}
\DTLsavedb{C}{C.csv} % doesn't write if before \begin{document}

\DTLdisplaydb{C}

\end{document}
```