# merge 3 csv file and create new file

Tags: datatool

i read topic: [Merge two .csv files and add missing rows?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/315528/merge-two-csv-files-and-add-missing-rows)
And i want change some things when i merge 3 different files

This minimal working example:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}{A.csv}
date,colA
2016-01-01,1
2016-01-02,4
2016-01-03,2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{B.csv}
date,colB0,colB1,colB2,colB3
2016-01-01,2,b10,b11,b12
2016-01-03,4,b20,b21,b22
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{D.csv}
date,colD0,colD1,colD2,colD3
2016-01-01,2,d10,d11,d12
2016-01-03,4,d20,d21,d22
\end{filecontents*}


% \DTLloaddb{A}{A.csv}
\DTLloaddb{B}{B.csv}
\DTLloaddb{D}{D.csv}
\DTLloaddb{E}{A.csv}

\DTLforeach{E}{\Date=date}{
    \DTLgetvalueforkey{\tmp}{colB0}{B}{date}{\Date}
    %\DTLgetvalueforkey{\tmp}{colB1}{B}{date}{\Date}
    \DTLappendtorow{colB0}{\DTLifnull{\tmp}{0}{\tmp}}
}

\begin{document}

\DTLsetseparator{,}
\DTLsetdelimiter{"}
\DTLsavedb{E}{E.csv} % doesn't write if before \begin{document}

\DTLdisplaydb{E}

\end{document}
```

Now, i want to create new file E with columns:

Date  colA   colB0   colB1    colB2 colD0 colD1 colD2

Please use DTLgetvalueforkey & Datatool.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the PDF output

[image]

And here is the CSV file  built by the code below

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents*}{A.csv}
date,colA
2016-01-01,1
2016-01-02,4
2016-01-03,2
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{B.csv}
date,colB0,colB1,colB2,colB3
2016-01-01,2,b10,b11,b12
2016-01-03,4,b20,b21,b22
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{D.csv}
date,colD0,colD1,colD2,colD3
2016-01-01,2,d10,d11,d12
2016-01-03,4,d20,d21,d22
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb{E}{A.csv}
\DTLloaddb{B}{B.csv}
\DTLloaddb{D}{D.csv}

% Specific request
% Now, i want to create new file E with columns:
% Date colA colB0 colB1 colB2 colD0 colD1 colD2
\DTLforeach{E}{\Date=date}{\DTLgetvalueforkey{\tmp}{colB0}{B}{date}{\Date}\DTLappendtorow{colB0}{\DTLifnull{\tmp}{0}{\tmp}}}
\DTLforeach{E}{\Date=date}{\DTLgetvalueforkey{\tmp}{colB1}{B}{date}{\Date}\DTLappendtorow{colB1}{\DTLifnull{\tmp}{0}{\tmp}}}
\DTLforeach{E}{\Date=date}{\DTLgetvalueforkey{\tmp}{colB2}{B}{date}{\Date}\DTLappendtorow{colB2}{\DTLifnull{\tmp}{0}{\tmp}}}
\DTLforeach{E}{\Date=date}{\DTLgetvalueforkey{\tmp}{colD0}{D}{date}{\Date}\DTLappendtorow{colD0}{\DTLifnull{\tmp}{0}{\tmp}}}
\DTLforeach{E}{\Date=date}{\DTLgetvalueforkey{\tmp}{colD1}{D}{date}{\Date}\DTLappendtorow{colD1}{\DTLifnull{\tmp}{0}{\tmp}}}
\DTLforeach{E}{\Date=date}{\DTLgetvalueforkey{\tmp}{colD2}{D}{date}{\Date}\DTLappendtorow{colD2}{\DTLifnull{\tmp}{0}{\tmp}}}

\begin{document}
Table E 
\DTLsetseparator{,}
\DTLsetdelimiter{"}
\DTLsavedb{E}{E.csv} % doesn't write if before \begin{document}
\DTLdisplaydb{E}
\end{document}
```